# In beamer insertshorttitle does not split on multiple lines in parbox

Tags: beamer

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Very long title that doesn't split on multiple text lines}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\parbox{2cm}{\insertshorttitle} % Fails

\parbox{2cm}{\inserttitle} % Works fine

\parbox{2cm}{Very long title that doesn't split on multiple text lines} % Works fine
}
\end{document}
```

Problem: When using the `\insertshorttitle` command the text does not split on multiple line within the parbox. How could this be solved?

**Edit:** `\insertitle` works fine. But I'd like to use `\insertshorttitle`.

Comment: Maybe putting the `\parbox` inside the `\title` macro?

Comment: The problem might be caused by the fact that `\insertshorttitle` inserts a link?

Comment: @samcarter is there a way to access the raw short title text without the link? Something like \thetitle but for the short version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution but the link to the title page is broken. I don't really care about the link.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Very long title that doesn't split on multiple text lines}

\makeatletter
\let\myshorttitle\beamer@shorttitle
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frame{
\parbox{2cm}{\myshorttitle}

\parbox{2cm}{Very long title that doesn't split on multiple text lines}
}
\end{document}
```